# How to customize file popup menu just on Dokan file system using C#?

Tags: c#, windows, filesystems, popupmenu, dokan

I mounted Dokan drive. I'd like to have file popup menu customized on that file system using C#.

Currently windows system supports file popup menu, but I wanna change whole thing and create my own menu.

Is that possible? How can I do that?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzJQ0.png)

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is not possible to replace the whole menu.

Comment: I found new way to do this using SharpShell nuget component. There is function to be able to have menu customized and that is path specific. So if I set the path as Dokan Drive path, this will solve problem.